# ZBS ZeroBraneStudio lua libs location in Mac OS

Tags: zerobrane

I wanted to debug openresty lua which is running in my local host. I installed ZBS IDE for that purpose in my MAC. I am going through the documentation available [at](http://notebook.kulchenko.com/zerobrane/debugging-openresty-nginx-lua-scripts-with-zerobrane-studio).

The instruction says I need to set the below in the nginx conf

```
lua_package_path '{ZBS}/lualibs/?/?.lua;{ZBS}/lualibs/?.lua;;';
lua_package_cpath '{ZBS}/bin/clibs/?.dll;;';
```

I am finding it really hard to find out the location of  in my mac. I installed the IDE my moving the dmg inside the application directory. Since I could not set this path, my ngix is failing to find the module 'mobdebug'.

Any idea as how to find the ZBS lua lib path in Mac OS.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed ZBS as the application, then `{ZBS}` in the paths needs to be replaced with something like `/Applications/ZeroBraneStudio.app/Contents/ZeroBraneStudio`, so the full paths becomes:

```
lua_package_path '/Applications/ZeroBraneStudio.app/Contents/ZeroBraneStudio/lualibs/?/?.lua;/Applications/ZeroBraneStudio.app/Contents/ZeroBraneStudio/lualibs/?.lua;;';
lua_package_cpath '/Applications/ZeroBraneStudio.app/Contents/ZeroBraneStudio/bin/clibs/?.dylib;;';
```